# css - how to make flex item 3 in a row and keeping 1:1 ratio when resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I want to make the flex item 3 in a row and keeping 1:1 ratio when resizing window.

[image]

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
        <div className="item">123</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0.1rem;
}
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-hamilton-iiwrh?file=/src/App.js

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *1:1 ratio when resizing window*?

Comment: @GalAbra I want the flex-item keep being a square when resizing

Comment: @GalAbra if you use wordpress, you can go to Media Page to resize the window

Comment: I still don't understand the expected behaviour. Can you attach screenshots of the example you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `display: grid` for `.container` and `aspect-ratio: 1/1` for `.item`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #1eaafc;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 130deg, #6c52d9, #1eaafc 85%, #3edfd7);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #171717;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 19%), 0 6px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 23%);
  color: #fff;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
</div>
```

---

#### [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)

> The aspect-ratio  CSS property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the box, which will be used in the calculation of auto sizes and some other layout functions.

So, `aspect-ratio:1/1` ensures that the `attr.width === attr.height` always.

#### ['fr' unit for grid layout](https://mozilladevelopers.github.io/playground/css-grid/04-fr-unit/)

> CSS Grid Layout introduces a new unit of length called fr, which is short for “fraction”. MDN defines the fr unit as a unit which represents a fraction of the available space in the grid container.

So for a 3 column layout we can write,

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
```

**The repeat notation** - If you find yourself repeating length units, use the CSS `repeat()` function

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

Comment: Using "aspect-ratio" is the easiest way to do it, but if you need Safari support it will not work. It doesn't work for older versions of Chrome or Firefox(2020/2021). If OP needs browser support for Safari I'd recommend going with the padding method.

Comment: @Arthur: safari supports `aspect-ratio` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

What about using grid system instead ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-ganguly-lzdg9

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid